# Display different components depending on state?

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular 2.
I've created a component with the following template.

```
<h1>My component</h1>
<placeholder?></placeholder?>
```

Depending on the state in my component I want to display different child components instead of the placeholder tag. Is that possible? How?

For example: Let's say I have injected a service into my component. If this service returns 1 I want to show ComponentOne and for all other values from the service I want to display the OtherComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) for this.

See [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for an example how to use it. I guess the wrapper used in the linked answer would work for you as well.

Comment: Link broken - now: [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Answer (score 0):

Use ***ngIf** for each component you want to display or not :

```
<component1 *ngIf="service.value1"></component1>

<component2 *ngIf="service.value2"></component2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `*ngIf` for applying your conditions along with dynamic component loader.
You can follow this plnkr for more reference too.

[Dynamic Component Loader Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/OEYeJv7UEQMrfTQibpGB/)

All you need to do is to apply `*ngIf` directive on div where you want to load the component.

For eg.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, View, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef } from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'dc',
  template: '<b>Some template</b>'
})   

class DynamicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="your condition">
        <div #container></div>
    </div>
  `
})   

export class App {
  dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader;
  constructor(dynamicComponentLoader: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.dynamicComponentLoader = dynamicComponentLoader;
    dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(DynamicComponent, elementRef, 'container');

  }

}
```